# How to deal with circular dependency in GraphQL resolvers (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

***I reformulated the question and answered it here:*** [My graphql resolvers have a circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704201/my-graphql-resolvers-have-a-circular-dependency)

I am trying to create circular dependency in ApolloGraphQL. The problem is that I can't figure out how to solve the circular references on the resolver side. The use case looks like this:

```
type Episode {

  Id: String

  ParentSeason: Season // I don't have this right now (circular dependency)

  // etc... A pretty complex type
}



type Season {

  Id: String

  EpisodeList: [Episode]

  // etc... A pretty complex type
}
```

The way I built this is by creating an Entity(simple class) from the database records and then I added an `asGqType()` function that adds the additional resolvers to the "raw" object. (I also have a REST API that's why)

The SeasonEntity looks like this:

```
class SeasonEntity {

  constructor(seasonDBRecord) {
      this.Id = seasonDBRecord.id;
      etc...
  }
  
  asGqType = () => {
    return {
      ...this,
      EpisodeList: () => {
          const episodeEntities = await episodeRepository.getEpisodes(); // returns EpisodeEntity[]
          return episodeEntities.map(episode => episode.asGqType() );
      }
      etc etc...
    }
 }
```

It looks really nice, you just call `asGqType()` and you don't have to deal with the child complexities.

But the problem appears when I try to extend the `EpisodeEntity.asGqType()` with `ParentSeason` as it would rely on SeasonEntity which already relies on EpisodeEntity. So javascript will never resolve this: it's normal, I agree.

How could I change this so that my entities can reference any other entity and be referenced by any other entity? I am not looking for a "quick fix" as I have a lot of complex entities. I've seen some people talking about `GraphQLObjectType` but I am not sure how to actually use that.

I am grateful for any advice, even on how to rearchitect all this.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: GraphQL allows for circular references in type definitions.

Comment: @MichelFloyd yes it does, but how can I leverage that and not bring too much complexity into my code(resolver)?

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a [one-to-many relationship](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-5#heading-one-to-many-relationships) between `Season` and `Episode`. This should be straightforward.

Your schema:

```
type Season {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  episodes: [Episode!]
}

type Episode: {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  number: Number!
  season: Season!
}
```

Let's assume these types map to two different tables in a relational database. The resolver for `episodes` should then be something like:

```
season: {
  episodes: ({ id }) => 
    episodeRepository.getEpisodes({ seasonId: id }) // depends on your ORM
}
```

And your resolver for an episode's `season` should be:

```
episode: {
  season: ({ seasonId }) => seasonRepository.getSeason({ id: seasonId }) 
}
```

> You don't have to `await` a resolver (unless you need to get some intermediate results), Apollo server will handle that for you.

I'm not sure about your ORM so can't be specific about the syntax of those two queries. The first one means: *return episodes for which the seasonId has the id of the season I'm resolving*. The second one means *return the season for which the id is equal to the seasonId (foreign key) of the episode I'm resolving.*

Comment: But this way, the `episodeRepository.getEpisodes` returns only raw data from the database. It doesn't return an episode with the `season` resolver function.

Comment: I don't get it how you leverage the resolver for the episode, when you create other types that reference an episode

Comment: I think I start seeing your point: my types have a lot of functions so that you could get everything you need from a simple query. I could dumb-down my objects and make my life easier. Having complex types and also leveraging repositories seems like an impossible mission. Am i right?

Comment: 1) Yes, `getEpisodes` only returns raw data from the db. That `resolves` the `episodes` field. 2) If you have other types that resolve to episodes that also have a foreign key into the episodes table you can use the same pattern as with seasons. 3) Your types are *not* complex by a long shot. These are straightforward GraphQL patterns. Read my full blog series to cover more relational <-> GraphQL cases.

Comment: So, imagine that both Episode and Season have like 5-6 fields that have custom resolvers. Right now, because the resolvers are contained in a class, (if both classes reference each other) I get into a circular dependency that javascript cannot resolve

Comment: Yes and? You won't usually need to replicate many of those, only the one that decides how to find the root object. Resolvers that compute values based on the other fields of an object can remain unchanged.

Comment: In class Episode I have to import class Season, and in class Season i have to import class Episode. I simply cannot run the code

Comment: You're going to need to create a repo with a minimal reproducible example. In any case it's not a GraphQL issue or constraint, more of an issue with how you're implementing your class structure.

Comment: What I have can be reduced to: Each repo returns the entire GQL Type (all "custom" resolvers are returned). So, `getEpisode` depends on `getSeason`, and vice-versa. It's a dependency that cannot be resolved by javascript (of course).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249972/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-alex-turdean).